# UILocalNotification Or EventKIt

Tags: iphone, localnotification

I have read the material regarding UILocalNotification , but there is no way i find to play a infinite loop sound when the notification  is fired ,  it does play for a short time with showing an alert, but i want to achieve the goal of playing a continuos sound by providing the option of snooze and quite . I have gone through the UIEvent Kit too but unable to find a way to achieve this goal. One more question is there a way to customize the alert button action which are provided by default by the apple.
looking for you guys early response
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did not do that but there is a function when local notification fires this function is invoked but before it invoked the ok or view or what ever you name the  button should be pressed after that you can sms code in that function and it should take care for that ...Hope This will help you